# How to add properly in VB.net options inside of an installer setup project using an installer class?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a question about how to get the option selected during the installation process from an installer setup project using an installer class?

This is the installer class added to the non-project setup

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Configuration.Install

Public Class Installer1

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'El Diseñador de componentes requiere esta llamada.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Agregue el código de inicialización después de llamar a InitializeComponent
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
        MyBase.Install(stateSaver)
        Dim valor As String = Me.Context.Parameters.Item("BUTTON4")
        MsgBox(valor)
    End Sub 

End Class
```

After that de customs actions of the setup project were defined, In the field of Properties of the Action CustomActionData = BUTTON4

[image]

Next, four button options were added to the project

[image]

However, at the time to run the installer `MsgBox(valor)` shows an empty string no matter the option selected, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The steps for pass input selection of the installer to the installer class are:

1: Make your project.
2: Add New Element -> Choose Installer Class
3: Create a Setup Project
4: In te Setup Project -> View -> User Interface
5- In Start add Buttons Options

Pay attention to the name of the variable BUTTON4 in my case holds the value of the option selected in the installer.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60fQA.png)

4: In the Setup Project -> View -> Custom Actions
5: In the Install Folder of Custom Actions -> Add Custom
Select the assembly of your project, and in the field CustomActionData Add the variable name to handle in the installer class

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6gcU.png)

6: In the installer class do the actions for the selected actions in the installer, in my case write a Config file

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
```

Imports System.Configuration.Install

Public Class Installer1

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    'El Diseñador de componentes requiere esta llamada.
    InitializeComponent()

    'Agregue el código de inicialización después de llamar a InitializeComponent

End Sub

Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
    MyBase.Install(stateSaver)

    Dim sIdioma As String = Me.Context.Parameters.Item("IDIOMA")
    Actualizar_Config_File(sIdioma)

End Sub

Private Sub Actualizar_Config_File(ByVal sIdioma As String)
    Dim sArchivo As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & DIR_DOC & DIR_CFIG
    Dim iNumeroArchivo As Integer = FreeFile() ' Obtiene un número
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    FileOpen(iNumeroArchivo, sArchivo, OpenMode.Output)

    For i = 0 To 1
        PrintLine(iNumeroArchivo, sIdioma)
    Next i

    FileClose(iNumeroArchivo) ' Cierra el archivo.
End Sub
```

End Class